# Changing specific shared library of linux executable

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, hardlink

I'm building an android application on a GNU/Linux based server and aapt is complaining that lib/libz.so.1 is out of date:

```
/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by .../aapt)
```

I've identified the problem and am trying to hard link the new zlib library to aapt so that it uses the updated library instead of the old libz.so.1 => libz.so.1.2.3 (because I'd like to avoid reconfiguring all programs that are using the existing zlib). Unfortunately, /lib and /aapt are located on separate partitions of the hard drive.

What's the best way to work around this? Is there an easy way to simply replace which version of libz aapt depends on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The easiest option is to put the correct version of the library somewhere (anywhere, separately) and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to that directory when executing `aapt`.
2. Put the correct version of the library somewhere like above, but change "rpath" of the `aapt` binary to look there using `chrpath`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary for more details.